# Can I temporarily turn off all CSS3 transitions/animations whilst an element is built?

Tags: javascript, animation, css, transition

I have created a rather complex Menu for a website. The menu lives from a huge amount of animation which is based on CSS3. However, when i navigate to a different page, the menu should build up initially - and without all the animations, but done JS-wise and not serverside.

Now i am wondering how i could completely disable all the transitions/animations temporarily, until the menu is built.

I thought about creating a subclass that overrides the animations but it does not seem to work, as it is always the animation/transition defined in the base class that is being used?

Comment: Potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131875/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-disable-css-transition-effects-temporarily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d suggest applying your animations/transitions via a class that’s added by JavaScript after the menu is built.

There is the [`animation-play-state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) property which can pause animations, but that only appeared (prefixed) in Safari 5 and Chrome 4 (as opposed to Safari 4 and Chrome 2 for the other animation properties), and I’m not sure if it’d work for your purposes.

Comment: I have this feeling that you are absolutely right. And i have this feeling of incredible joy of not having thought of this before i wrote those 2.500 lines. I still dream of an easier solution though.

Comment: I know what you mean. Not sure if it’s easier — you could remove the class in question via JavaScript when the menu starts building, and re-add it after it’s done. (Although if there are other styles in the class apart from animation, you’d lose those too.)

Comment: Yes, that's the point. It is pretty complex. What generally is a mystery to me, is why it is not possible to set an transition/animation with a new class and thus be able to override one that has been defined before. If that were possible, for example a "fade" transition could be timed differently than the according "appear" transition (when setting from opacity 0-1 and reverse)

Comment: Oh — I added a mention of `-webkit-animation-play-state` to the answer — thought I had before, although I’m not sure it’ll help your situation.

Comment: For transitions, I think the intention was to keep them very simple in implementation, at the expense of flexibility. For animations, I think you can set the `-webkit-animation-name` property to `none` to disable animations.

Comment: Unfortunately i use both, but more transitions than animations - and even more unfortunately, it i used in a public front-end. While being aware that many users won't be seeing any animations at all, i should implement a more fitting solution. I slowly get to the conclusion that i won't be able to get around restructuring all of it according to your suggestions.

Comment: Yeah — I think to achieve what you want, you’ll need to get your JavaScript to handle the adding of transitions.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the `transition-duration` to `0s` while building the menu and then set it back to the desired value afterwards.