# Is addClass() async?

Tags: jquery, css, transition

It should remove class `transition` (thus CSS transition property), move the div at 200px (**immediately**), re-apply the `transition` css property and than animate (taking 1 second) the div to the right. Instead, its frozen.

It looks like apply the `css left` property takes more time of removing `transition` by class? Or is `addClass()` async?

```js
var elem = $('#elem');

elem.removeClass('transition');
elem.css('left', 200);
elem.addClass('transition');
elem.css('left', 0);
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#elem {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
.transition.linear.scritta {
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -o-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="elem" class="transition linear scritta"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you add and `Event` to this code. As in why it should happen?

Comment: I don't have the docs at hand, but from my experience the javascript evaluator of modern browsers are smart. If you just use: addClass(a)/removeClass(a) in the same call, they will skip the addClass in the first place. You can try to encapsulate this calls further.

Comment: @NicoO: if that's true, that's not smart, its unpredictable!

Comment: Are you expecting it to move to the left, then move back to the right?

Comment: No. Transition from the right (taking 1 second).

Comment: It appears that the `elem.css('left', 200);` is what's asynchronous here.

Comment: ok, not sure what's "really" async, but I noticed that funny things happened when I added alert statements in between all the commands there.

Comment: @A.Wolff OP is expecting that the transition would happen from left:200 to left:0; the shift to left:200 would be immediate, without a transition.

Comment: @andi Ok, i misinterpreted expected result but my previous comment is still valid though. EDIT: wait, now i'm confused indeed

Comment: Here there's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670397/bypassing-transition-and-changing-a-property-instantly

Comment: I posted an answer just to demonstrate what I meant with the alert statements.  Please take a look.

Comment: Finally, also if too late here is a demonstration of the problem I meant in my first comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fx5uao82/2/

Answer (score 7):

No, `addClass` is synchronous. You can look at the [source code](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js):

```
addClass: function( value ) {
  var classes, elem, cur, curValue, clazz, j, finalValue,
      i = 0;

  if ( jQuery.isFunction( value ) ) {
    return this.each( function( j ) {
      jQuery( this ).addClass( value.call( this, j, getClass( this ) ) );
    } );
  }

  if ( typeof value === "string" && value ) {
    classes = value.match( rnothtmlwhite ) || [];

    while ( ( elem = this[ i++ ] ) ) {
      curValue = getClass( elem );
      cur = elem.nodeType === 1 && ( " " + stripAndCollapse( curValue ) + " " );

      if ( cur ) {
        j = 0;
        while ( ( clazz = classes[ j++ ] ) ) {
          if ( cur.indexOf( " " + clazz + " " ) < 0 ) {
            cur += clazz + " ";
          }
        }

        // Only assign if different to avoid unneeded rendering.
        finalValue = stripAndCollapse( cur );
        if ( curValue !== finalValue ) {
          elem.setAttribute( "class", finalValue );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return this;
}
```

You would see the same result if you used native APIs instead of jQuery.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');

elem.classList.remove('transition');
elem.style.left = '200px';
elem.classList.add('transition');
elem.style.left = '0px';
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#elem {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
.transition.linear.scritta {
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -o-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="elem" class="transition linear scritta"></div>
</div>
```

It seems that browsers don't directly update the document when you change a CSS style. That could produce paintings and relayouts and expensive operations, which would be useless if you are going to change more styles.

So they wait a bit to let you change more styles, and then they update them all simultaneously.

As a solution, you can try using asynchroneous code:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  elem.style.left = '0px';
});
```

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');

elem.classList.remove('transition');
elem.style.left = '200px';
elem.classList.add('transition');
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  elem.style.left = '0px';
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#elem {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
.transition.linear.scritta {
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -o-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="elem" class="transition linear scritta"></div>
</div>
```

Force an update with `getComputedStyle` seems to work too.

```js
getComputedStyle(elem).transitionDuration; // force update
```

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');

elem.classList.remove('transition');
elem.style.left = '200px';
elem.classList.add('transition');
getComputedStyle(elem).transitionDuration; // force update
elem.style.left = '0px';
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#elem {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
.transition.linear.scritta {
  -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  -o-transition: all 1.0s linear;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="elem" class="transition linear scritta"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So why it render as async!

Comment: Why this happens? Are transition faster to be applied?

Comment: @mark, do you perchance have jQuery UI included in the same page? It overloads [addClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/) and makes it asynchronous.

Comment: @markzzz Not sure if this is in the spec. But note CSS Transitions is just a draft, don't rely much on it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: no! Check the fiddle, there isn't jquery ui.

Comment: @Oriol: CSS transitions is just a draft? What do you mean? :O

Comment: @Oriol: now sure what you mean with "use asynch function". Where did you call `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/ is a Working Draft and https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/ is an Editor’s Draft. There is no Candidate Recommendation or Recommendation yet.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` is asynch. You call it at the end. Click "Show code snippet" to see the full code.

Comment: It appears that add/remove of `.transition` isn't required for rAF and gCS solutions to work.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame(func)` is a function call.

Comment: This seems to be the right way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670397/bypassing-transition-and-changing-a-property-instantly

Comment: It sure doesn't feel synchronous. I can run add/remove functions one after another and the rendered state is inconsistent