# Disable transitions during stylesheet change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I tried this solution:

[What is the cleanest way to disable CSS transition effects temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131875/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-disable-css-transition-effects-temporarily)

but it doesn't work. I still see stuff animating.

```
$('body').addClass('notransition'); // the class that doesn't work  
$('body')[0].offsetHeight;
$('#main_style').attr('href', newStyleUrl);
$('body').removeClass('notransition');
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: What is your CSS code?

Comment: The notransition class? is the same as in the linked answer. Other than that I have a few transitions, some of them use the "all" property. I suspect those cause the problems, but I don't understand why are they still running :s

Comment: Do you apply the transitions to the body element?

Comment: no, body has no transitions

Comment: So, referring to the question you linked, you have to apply the `notransition` class to the element that has transition applied, not to the body element

Comment: But my class is defined as `.notransition *{...}`. It is supposed to be applied to all elements

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46606/discussion-between-andrea-parodi-and-alex)

Comment: Post your styles. Or create a demo. The error is pretty simple, I suspect.