# Turn animation off using @Media Query

Tags: css, media-queries

I would like to stop all animation on all mobile devices.  How would I achieve this task?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131875/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-disable-css-transition-effects-temporarily) could be helpful. All you'd have to do is enable that process when the useragent is mobile.  Either that or just set that `.notransition` class to a media query that specifies when the screen is smaller (denoting a mobile device)

Comment: @AlexanderLozada Thank you, I am checking into it.  I am unfamiliar with JS, Hope it's not to painful.

Comment: Somebody hopefully might be able to offer a more concrete solution below.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada If I posted any code would that be better?

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by Alexander in the comments above works, and you can use media queries instead like so:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  * {
   -webkit-transition: none !important;
   -moz-transition: none !important;
   -o-transition: none !important;
   -ms-transition: none !important;
   transition: none !important;
  }
}
```

Use what ever media queries you use for mobile devices and use the `*` wildcard to apply the no transition to all elements.

If you have animations as well as transitions you can try setting the `animation-name:none;` which *should* disable all animations.

Comment: From the code posted http://jsfiddle.net/EkZZf/ How would u write it?

Comment: From the example that LcLk provided, it'd be as simple as putting it in the CSS box.  http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/EkZZf/1/