# Disable JQuery automatic animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes when using JQuery to set the css attribute of an element such as "height", "max-height", it automatically binds animation to the change. Sometimes it is awesome, but it is not always necessary. Is there a way to disable this kind of animation?

Actually what is the exact situation that causes JQuery to automatically bind animations? because I don't always see this kind of behavior. I am not using JQuery-UI.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: Does the element in question has an `animation` property?

Comment: @EricPhillips I see this behavior in the application I am working on and all I did is .css("max-height", xxx), since the div that is contained should have greater height. I didn't catch the pattern of JQuery in this producing the animation.

Comment: @MinusFour No. I checked using .hasOwnProperty("animation"). It has the animate function (it is JQuery object), and it has null for "arguments" and "caller", 4 for "length", and "" for "name".

Comment: I meant the css property `animation`.

Comment: I had transition. I think this is the cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the element you are changing the height of has a `css` transition property that is responsibe for the animation.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.myClass').css('width', '100px');
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.transition {
  transition: width 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
with transition
<div class="myClass transition">
</div>

without transition
<div class="myClass">
</div>
```

#### Borrowing from [What is the cleanest way to disable CSS transition effects temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131875/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-disable-css-transition-effects-temporarily)

You can then create a `class` that will override the transition property and toggle that class

```
.notransition {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

#### Note

If you go this route, you may run into the issue of needing to `reflow` the `css`

From [What is the cleanest way to disable CSS transition effects temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131875/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-disable-css-transition-effects-temporarily) once again:

> There are various ways to do this - see here for some. The closest
>   thing there is to a 'standard' way of doing this is to read the
>   offsetHeight property of the element.
>
> One solution that actually works, then, is
>
> ```
> $someElement.addClass('notransition'); // Disable transitions
> doWhateverCssChangesYouWant($someElement);
> $someElement[0].offsetHeight; // Trigger a reflow, flushing the CSS
> changes $someElement.removeClass('notransition'); // Re-enable
> transitions
> ```

Comment: This is very likely. The element uses a class css that does have the transition. So I basically need to set transition to "" using jquery, and fill it back up after the height is changed?

Comment: there's a good solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131875/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-disable-css-transition-effects-temporarily recommends creating a class to disable the transition and toggling that class, rather than the property directly.  that way you don't have to worry about resetting the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jQuery.fx.off** parameter to define if animation should be used. [Read about it here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fx.off/)

Also you can modify css values directly without modifying function like

```
    $("#id").css('height', '100px');
```

instead of

```
    $("#id").height(100);
```

Comment: Is there a function to set the maxheight like this?

Comment: `$("#id").css('max-height', '100px');`

Comment: CSS has **max-height** property so yup - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp