# How to turn off CSS for faster automation tests execution?

Tags: javascript, css, selenium-webdriver

Reference:

1. [What is the cleanest way to disable CSS transition effects temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131875/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-disable-css-transition-effects-temporarily#comment74107319_16575811)
2. http://onezeronull.com/2016/10/06/disable-css-transitions-and-animations-temporarily-or-permanently/

Whenever I need to run test JavaScript I use `JavascriptExecutor` but none of the blogs above clarifies how it can be done with it.

I tried:

```
js.executeScript(".notransition {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}");
```

But it does nothing for me.

**Edit:**

I tried after the answer provided by @AmerllicA

```
public void turnOffCss () {
    navigate("https://www.bureauofdigital.com");
    js.executeScript("*, *:before, *:after {
     -webkit-transition: none !important;
     -moz-transition: none !important;
     -ms-transition: none !important;
     -o-transition: none !important;        
     transition: none !important;

     -webkit-transform: none !important;
     -moz-transform: none !important;
     -ms-transform: none !important;
     -o-transform: none !important;        
     transform: none !important;
    }");
}
```

Comment: No no no dude, its a `CSS` code not `JavaScript`, if you wanna use this code, you must make a `style` tag, put these `CSS`es append to it and then append the `style` tag to `head` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put another answer for your exact question on `JavaScript Executor`. let's to clarify the `JavaScript` code,

1. make a `style` tag element.
2. add `id` attribute with `style-tag` value.
3. make a string of that `CSS`es I answered in another answer.
4. put or append the string into `style` tag.
5. append the `style` to `head` tag in `DOM`.

Now let's write above states to `JavaScript` codes:

```
const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
styleElement.setAttribute('id','style-tag');
const styleTagCSSes = document.createTextNode('*,:after,:before{-webkit-transition:none!important;-moz-transition:none!important;-ms-transition:none!important;-o-transition:none!important;transition:none!important;-webkit-transform:none!important;-moz-transform:none!important;-ms-transform:none!important;-o-transform:none!important;transform:none!important}');
styleElement.appendChild(styleTagCSSes);
document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
```

With this codes you could import my another answer `CSS`es to `DOM`. so you can put below string to your `JavaScript Executor`:

```
"const styleElement = document.createElement('style');styleElement.setAttribute('id','style-tag');const styleTagCSSes = document.createTextNode('*,:after,:before{-webkit-transition:none!important;-moz-transition:none!important;-ms-transition:none!important;-o-transition:none!important;transition:none!important;-webkit-transform:none!important;-moz-transform:none!important;-ms-transform:none!important;-o-transform:none!important;transform:none!important}');styleElement.appendChild(styleTagCSSes);document.head.appendChild(styleElement);"
```

If you wanna revert this action, just use:

```
document.getElementById('style-tag').remove();
```

Hope these codes help you.

Answer (score 5):

Your question title is `How to turn of CSS` and what does it means? if you mean turn of all transition use below code:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -ms-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;        
    transition: none !important;
}
```

I guess your access is just by `JavaScript` so you can not access to `:before` or `:after` so just add `*` to `CSS`es to omit all `transitions`.

But some animations and lovely motions are made by `transform` `translate` `CSS` property method, so if you wanna omit all animations and motions, you must use below code:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -ms-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;        
    transition: none !important;

    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    -moz-transform: none !important;
    -ms-transform: none !important;
    -o-transform: none !important;        
    transform: none !important;
}
```

This code absolutely smash all of website UI but maybe help you to run your test.