# JS: How to remove animations rather than just stopping them?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to remove an animation? When I run `document.getAnimations()`, I see a list of my animations but I want to remove some after they they are completed.  Is there a way to do this?  I checked the Web Animation API but didn't see it in the documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the cleanest way to disable CSS transition effects temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131875/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-disable-css-transition-effects-temporarily)

Comment: Can you clarify what `remove` means, exactly, as opposed to `just stopping`?  If you mean remove the animation, how is that different from stopping the animation?  If you want to remove the entire elements, [there is an example in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAnimations#Examples).

Comment: thanks @Don'tPanic. I meant to remove just the animation from the array that `getAnimations()` returns.  I think removing the element is the only way to remove the Animation that is attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for the `animationEnd` event on an element and then set `el.style.animation = 'none'`.

Comment: I think `animationEnd` is only fired for CSS animations, right?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event

Comment: Ah, I'd assumed you were doing CSS animations. How are you animating?

Comment: standard JS web animation API